# I caught the source of the random background beeps on Windows 10 with Process Monitor. Now what is it?

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds

I'm getting random background notification sorts of beeps occasionally (multiple times per day). There are no notifications in the notification area to explain the source of the sounds.

I first thought it might be people logging onto or out of my friends lists on Steam, but that wasn't it. I used Process Monitor and captured three instances of it, but I'm not sure what they are. Can anyone interpret this picture for me?

[image: Process Monitor Capture]

Comment: The .wav file being played is connected to the sound played when a mass storage device is removed. So have you disconnected your storage devices to prevent the sound from being played

Comment: It is the "hardware removed" sound being played so either some device is being removed and plugged back in or there is some hardware fault. It could be a slightly dodgy USB connector shifting and disconnecting either a keyboard or mouse or memory stick, or one of those devices is failing somehow. Unless your screen is going black, which I would expect you to have noticed, USB is the most likely devices to be easily unplugged.

Comment: As @Mokubai states, occasionally a USB device disconnects, and often reconnects a second later, with a *ding* for each event. Sometimes Windows itself is at fault, for no apparent reason, but I have one powered USB hub which frequently disconnected, until I attached it, and its cables to a metal plate that serves as a heat-sink and to keep attached cables (both external power and USB) from wiggling.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I discovered that it was actually my earbuds wired to my system audio. I just moved to a dry climate, and I was getting static discharge periodically that caused the quick hardware disconnects.